# String in Java can we convert "Hello" into Hello

Tags: java

Hello all I an new to java I just want to know that can we convert `"Hello"` in `Hello`. I have gone through the internet answers but found that if any string has `""` in that so we can use the replace method of java. So I just want to convert the `"Hello"` into `Hello`. So if you know please help

suppose

```
   String s="Hello"
    //Required Operation
    System.out.println(s);//It should  print Hello.
```

So if you know please help me. Actually I have a file which contains lots of data having `" "` and I only want that data without double quotes so is it possible to convert that.

Comment: You already posted an answer. Use replace.

Comment: I couldn't understand how can i convert "Hello" in to Hello using replace.

Comment: If you know please help me i am new to java

Comment: It *does* print `Hello`. No `replace()` method required. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
String s = "\"hello\"";
String result = s.replaceAll("\"", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

Actually if you declare your string `String s="Hello"`, the variable `s` will not contain any quotes, because the quotes are Java syntax and mark the start and end of the String.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Comment: `replaceAll` is not necessary. `replace` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

As all the other answers you're able to use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

But their is another solution if you just want to erase the 1st and last char of your string ( so your " here) is to use substring like:

```
str = "Hello";
str = str.substring(0,str.length()-2);
```

I think that it could work for you